# Django Comment app

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates

Following the Django tutorial, i got a
    `{% get_comment_count for entry as comment_count %}` 
to work.

On the page I now see a message saying that there are 0 comments. I'm a little confused though because i specifically went back to the model and added a comment. what is this counting, and based on what? Why isn't it counting the comment I added? (I added it through the admin page)

Also, what is the "Object ID" that you see when adding a comment from the admin page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use [dialogos](https://github.com/eldarion/dialogos)?

No sense in ignoring the **DRY** concept that Django is built upon.